# How to check when a player is doing sth with the reciepie book in mc 1.19.2

Tags: java, minecraft

so I'm trying to make a global inventory that updates whenever basically anything related to a player inventory happens. Everything works but whenever a player goes about shift-clicking in the recipe book it's not registered by any conventional means (at least I think) What I had done up till now is used:

```
@EventHandler
    public void onInvClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        InvUpdate = true;
        invupdateplayer = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
    }
```

But the problem is that this code doesn't register receipe book events, which is what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to listen for this?

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of research, there are two possible solutions that I have found. In `InventoryClickEvent`, there is a method called `.isShiftClick` which detects if the interaction is a shift click. The other thing I found is something called `PrepareItemCraftEvent` which I believe checks to see if the recipe book is used. However, I haven't used the event before, so I'm not 100% sure.